# Git rebase with copied files

Tags: git, rebase

I have a commit affecting file X. In the mean time, file X was copied into file Y and all changes from now on are supposed to happen on file Y. How, can I "rebase" the changes I applied to file X to file Y?

Comment: There is no wizardry in Git that could do what you want automatically. You have to do it manually.

Comment: your solution below does what I wanted to achieve, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with *two* rebase operations. This is worth it only if there are many commits that change X, but should actually change Y.

The idea is to introduce an auxiliary commit that renames (instead of copies) file X, then rebase on top of that commit. Then Git is able to transplant all the changes made to file X to change file Y.

We start with this situation:

```
    S--T--U--V--W         <-- many commits that change X
   /
--B--C                    <-- this commit copies file X to Y
```

And we want to arrive at this situation:

```
--B--C                    <-- this commit copies file X to Y
      \
       S'-T'-U'-V'-W'     <-- many commits that change Y
```

First, we introduce a new commit that renames file X to Y:

```
git checkout B
git mv X Y
git commit -m "auxiliary commit: rename X to Y"
```

We now have

```
    S--T--U--V--W         <-- many commits that change X
   /
--B--C                    <-- this commit copies file X to Y
   \
    R                     <-- this commit renames file X to Y
```

Now we can rebase on top of that commit:

```
git rebase HEAD W
```

This should not produce any conflicts and run through smoothly. We arrive at this situation:

```
    S--T--U--V--W         <-- many commits that change X
   /
--B--C                    <-- this commit copies file X to Y
   \
    R                     <-- this commit renames file X to Y
     \
      S"-T"-U"-V"-W"      <-- many commits that change Y
```

This branch we can now rebase on top of `C`:

```
git rebase --onto C R
```

to get to the result:

```
    S--T--U--V--W         <-- many commits that change X
   /
--B--C                    <-- this commit copies file X to Y
   \  \
    R  S'-T'-U'-V'-W'     <-- many commits that change Y
     \
      S"-T"-U"-V"-W"      <-- many commits that change Y
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternative would be to read the X diff into a patch file, edit the patch file to be about Y instead X, and apply the patch file with the `patch` utility.

But this would fail, I think, if there turn out to be merge conflicts.